# Formato de data em Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, data

Estou usando o MySQL como base de dados para um projeto desenvolvido com Laravel. Porém, preciso converter o formato de data padrão (YYYY-MM-DD) para o formato "DD-MM-YYY". Como posso fazer essa conversão?

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).

Answer (score 4):

tenta assim:

```
date("d/m/Y",strtotime($data))
```

talvez isso resolva